# How to include a php variable in json and pass to ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

*My Code*

```
var json = xmlhttp.responseText; //ajax response from my php file
obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj.result);
```

*And in my php code*

```
 $result = 'Hello';

 echo '{
        "result":"$result",
        "count":3
       }';
```

The problem is: when I alert `obj.result`, it shows `"$result"`, instead of showing `Hello`.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The basic problem with your example is that `$result` is wrapped in single-quotes. So the first solution is to unwrap it, eg:

```
$result = 'Hello';
echo '{
    "result":"'.$result.'",
    "count":3
}';
```

But this is still not "good enough", as it is always possible that `$result` could contain a `"` character itself, resulting in, for example, `{"result":""","count":3}`, which is still invalid json. The solution is to escape the `$result` before it is inserted into the json.

This is actually very straightforward, using the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
$result = 'Hello';
echo '{
    "result":'.json_encode($result).',
    "count":3
}';
```

or, even better, we can have PHP do the entirety of the json encoding itself, by passing in a whole array instead of just `$result`:

```
$result = 'Hello';
echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => $result,
    'count' => 3
));
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to encode the data properly:

```
$data = array(
    "result" => $result,
    "count"  => 3
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using single quotes in your echo, therefore no string interpolation is happening

use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$arr = array(
    "result" => $result,
    "count" => 3
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

As a bonus, `json_encode` will properly encode your response!

Comment: I have tried this too. but it shows the same

echo '{
        "result":"'.$result.'",
        "count":3
       }';

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result = 'Hello';
echo '{
   "result":"'.$result.'",
   "count":3
}';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = 'Hello';

$json_array=array(
  "result"=>$result,
  "count"=>3
)
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

That's all.