# How to send data to php script and get back result to form with AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a problem with get back result from php script. I see in debug that the message is send correct but i cannot receive result.
I wanted to put r_volume and n_heaters it in 2 read only fields
Can You help me ? Thanks.

HTML form:

```
<div id="CalcForm" class="mt-5" >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                        <label>Length(m)</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="length" name="length" placeholder="ex. 4.5" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                        <label>Height(m)</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="height" name="height" placeholder="ex. 2.5" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                        <label>Width(m)</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="width" name="width" placeholder="ex. 3.5" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 mb-4">
                                    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CalcForm('5','3','4')">Send!</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label>Room volume:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="r_volume" readonly>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label>Number of heaters:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n_heaters" readonly>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Ajax Script:

```
         <script>
        function CalcForm(length,height,width) {
          if (length.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("r_volume").innerHTML = "test";
            return;
          } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("r_volume").innerHTML = this.responseText;
              }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "calculator.php?length=" + length + "&" + "height=" + height + "&" + "width=" + width, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
          }
        }
        </script>
```

And PHP file:

```
<?php
$length = $_REQUEST["length"];
$height = $_REQUEST["height"];
$width = $_REQUEST["width"];
$r_volume = ( $length * $height * $width );
$n_heaters = ceil($r_volume / 20);
echo $r_volume;
//echo $n_heaters;?>
```

Comment: instead of `.innerHTML` try with `.value` . i.e : `document.getElementById("r_volume").value`

Comment: It works thank You :) can You tell me how about second value, how to pass it back?

Comment: I **recommend** to add that value in `json` and passed the same to your `ajax` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12488824/10606400) and get that in ajax `var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText)` and access the same using `data.volume ..etc` and the other way which i **don't recommend** is just do `echo $r_volume .' ,'. $n_heaters;` then use `split` at js side to separate the values. and get the same.